# Passive sentence

Tags: grammar

Why in this sentence used simple present of "control", because I'm sure IRQL is something to be checked (object)?

"The IRQL level of an interrupt **controls** when the interrupt may be processed."

I think it would be better write:
"The IRQL level of an interrupt is controlled when the interrupt may be processed."

Comment: Hello, Reza. Have you looked up 'control' and checked example sentences? Does the subject need to reference a volitional agent (ie usually a person) or is it possible to use a non-sentient causative?

Comment: If the sentence is about microprocessor control signals, then the quoted sentence is correct. Interrupts have a priority level, which controls when it can be processed. A low priority interrupt cannot be processed while a higher one is active. But a high priority interrupt will interrupt a lower priority one. The proposed rewrite makes little sense in this context.

Comment: Hi Dears, I thought this sentence is double passive that the first object can convert to subject and passive verb (is controlled) convert to simple present (controls), because IRQL is an input request and can not control any things and actually is controlled by the CPU.

Comment: The IRQL **level** is a redundancy, because **IRQL** already abbreviates "Interrupt Request Level". Anyway, it is the IRQ signal which does the controlling, and its level determines *how* it does that controlling. Its level is not controlled by anything: it is inherent (although it might be programmable). So the proposed version makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you Weather Vane!

Comment: I agree with Weather Vane 